# Shall I encrypt data files in an iPhone game?

Tags: iphone, encryption, game-center

I'm making a turned based game for iPhone. I've got a couple of questions.

1.
Shall I bother with encrypting the data that is sent between the players?

2.
I'm also storing data files that contain help data. As an example, one such file demonstrates the game controls. Given the data in that file, it might be possible to make an understanding of the data in the turn data, but I would say that it's quite complicated. Shall I bother with this kind of security issues? I guess the information can be used to be number one on the ranking :). I guess these files are viewable on a jail broken device?

3.
If I encrypt the files, will cheating be eliminated then?

Answer (score 0):

**1 / 2:** I don't think you should bother with encrypting the files. While it stops them being tampered with, if you're just sending turns back and forth there isn't any real point. Sure, they could be intercepted and changed, but unless this is some AAA game where changing this info would affect a lot of players, I really don't see the point.

**3:** No, cheating won't be eliminated. Even if you encrypt something, someone will always be able to find a way around your encryption. Sure, there might not be a method now, but there will be some day.

Comment: The reason why encryption doesn't help is because his scenario requires broken key management. There is no reason to believe that the encryption itself will be broken during the lifetime of a typical application.